# Strong induction on ℕ with function α → ℕ

Tags: lean, beginner, lean3

I have the following problem. I have a type $\alpha$, function $f : \alpha \to \mathbb{N}$ and predicate $P : \alpha \to \mathrm{Prop}$ and I want to prove that for all $a : \alpha, P a$.

How could prove this with induction on the value $f a$, i.e. cases where $f a = 0$ and $f a > 0$?

My current trial in Lean looks like this:

```
lemma foo (α : Type) (f : α → ℕ) (P : α → Prop)
  (base : ∀ a : α, f a = 0 → P a)
  (ind : ∀ a : α, f a > 0 → ∃ b : α, f b < f a) :
  ∀ a : α, P a
```

In the inductive case, I want to get the hypothesis `P b`.
I tried to use `nat.strong_induction_on`, but I can't figure out what to apply it on.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your `ind` term looks a bit odd to me. I would have expected the "exists" term to be something like `(∀ b, f b < f a -> P b)`. Your term says that there exists some b such that `P b`.

Comment: Aha sorry, I actually wrote it incorrectly, the `ind` term should actually be something like `(ind : ∀ a : α, f a > 0 → ∃ b : α, f b < f a)`. But I don't apriori know that `P b`.
I fixed it in the question.
Perhaps `ind` is not the best name for this term.

Comment: Well, that hypothesis doesn't give you an inductive step: you still need something that says how to get `P a` out of `P b` when `f b < f a`.

Comment: Add ``(∀ a : α, f a = 0 + f a > 0)`` in your definition of ``foo``. Then pattern match on ``case``. You should provide some term of type ``∀ n : ℕ, n = 0 + n > 0``.

Comment: P.S. By ``+`` I mean the sum type. I am not sure what symbol Lean uses.

Comment: I also have that, I can get `P a` given `P b` i.e. `ind` gives me a `b` s.t. `f b < f a` and a function `P b -> P a` , but my assumption doesn't give me `P b`.
That's why I want to use induction on ℕ somehow.

Comment: @KANG Rongji
I do have that, since `f a : ℕ`, so we can use `cases` on nat, the problem is then I don't get the inductive hypothesis I want.

Comment: Ohhh... I see...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
theorem foo (α : Type) (f : α → ℕ) (P : α → Prop)
  (base : ∀ a, f a = 0 → P a)
  (ind : ∀ a, (∀ b, f b < f a → P b) → P a) :
  ∀ a, P a
:=
begin
  intro a,
  let Q := λ n, ∀ a, f a = n → P a,
  have Qstep : ∀ (n : ℕ), (∀ (m : ℕ), m < n → Q m) → Q n,
  { intros n h a ξ,
    apply (ind a),
    intros b fb_lt_fa,
    rewrite ξ at fb_lt_fa,
    apply (h (f b)) fb_lt_fa, refl 
  },
  exact @well_founded.fix _ Q nat.lt nat.lt_wf Qstep (f a) a rfl,
end
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed, thank you.

Comment: You don't need the `@` on that last line, `exact nat.lt_wf.fix Qstep (f a) a rfl` works too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to prove [Andrej Bauer's corrected statement](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/1052/347) using the `induction` tactic:

```
theorem foo (α : Type) (f : α → ℕ) (P : α → Prop)
  (ind : ∀ a, (∀ b, f b < f a → P b) → P a) :
  ∀ a, P a :=
begin
  intro a,
  induction hn : f a using nat.strong_induction_on with n ih generalizing a,
  apply ind,
  intros b fb_lt_fa,
  rw hn at fb_lt_fa,
  exact ih _ fb_lt_fa _ rfl,
end
```

We're using lots of its optional features at once here:

- `hn : _` lets us remember that the variable we're inducting on is equal to `f a`
- `using nat.strong_induction_on` tells it to use a non-default recursion scheme
- `generalizing a` ensure that `a` is in a binder in our inductive hypothesis `ih`

Note that we don't need `base`.

Comment: If terseness is wanted, everything after the `induction` line can be replaced by `subst hn, exact ind _ (λ b fb_lt_fa, ih _ fb_lt_fa _ rfl)`

Comment: Indeed; though I was trying to be less cryptic than Andrej's answer, not more!

Comment: I do wonder if `induction h : _` should handle the `subst` and `rfl` automatically, but haven't thought about it very hard.